# What is the difference between SVI and online HDP algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, topic-models, online-algorithms, variational-bayes

I'm going over the [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume14/hoffman13a/hoffman13a.pdf) by Hoffman et. al. titled "**Stochastic Variational Inference**" (SVI) where the authors present an algorithm for Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP) topic models. I'm comparing this with a [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v15/wang11a/wang11a.pdf) by Chong Wang et. al. titled "**Online Variational Inference for the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process**" where the authors present an online HDP algorithm (also implemented in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html)). And I'm wondering between the differences of these two algorithms. In what ways SVI HDP is different from online HDP?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a difference; the online method in Chong et al. is an instance of the method later generalized in Hoffman et al., a fact that is tucked into a footnote in the SVI paper:

> This section is organized as follows. We first give some background on the Dirichlet process and its definition via Sethuraman’s stick breaking construction, which is a distribution on the infinite simplex. We then show how to use this construction to form the HDP topic model and how to use stochastic variational inference to approximate the posterior.$^7$
>
> 7. This algorithm first appeared in Wang et al. (2011). Here we place it in the more general context of Section 2 and
>    relate it to stochastic inference for LDA.

Comment: interesting. nice catch!

Comment: @VadimSmolyakov Read a paper as many times as I have the SVI paper, you remember a few things :)